# Check all test files are compilable

Tags: elixir, ex-unit

I have a case when I need to check that all files in my app's test suite are compilable.

I'm trying to create a list of all files and then compile them, but it turns out I can't do it without starting ExUnit.

```
find apps/*/test -name "*.exs" | xargs elixirc

== Compilation error in file apps/api/test/api/request_validators/validator_test.exs ==
** (RuntimeError) cannot use ExUnit.Case without starting the ExUnit application, please call ExUnit.start() or explicitly start the :ex_unit app
    expanding macro: ExUnit.Case.__using__/1
```

How to check that all test files are compilable without actually running tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper solution would be to indeed start `ExUnit`, compile all the files and examine the outcome.

```
mix run -e 'ExUnit.start(); exit({:shutdown, (if match?({:ok, _, _}, Kernel.ParallelCompiler.compile(Path.wildcard("test/**/*.exs"))), do: 0, else: 1)})'
```

That way you might also explicitly specify the error code to return.

Comment: It works faster than my approach, thanks!
I had to change the path to `"apps/*/test/**/*.exs"` for it to work, because I'm running tests in an umbrella app.

Comment: It's stopped working for me. However, the error is too specific to share it here.

Comment: This code is indeed bullet-proof. I am positive the issue is induced.

Comment: The error is about missing configuration in one of the umbrella apps when compiling another. There are no such errors when I just run tests.

Comment: Ah, umbrella, yes. You probably should check how [tag:elixir] compiler deals with umbrellas and if there are some specific quirks there.

Answer (score 1):

I've found an answer.

Just run tests with some tag that doesn't exist. This will compile all tests but none of them will be actually run

```
mix test --only whatever
```

**UPDATE**: this only works for umbrella apps. For a regular app, nonexistent tag leads to an error code `1` (see comments to this question).

It's possible to create a workaround: have an empty test that is always green and mark it with the tag.

See also the accepted answer for a better solution.

Comment: This works if you visually inspect the output, but the status of the unix status of the command is 1, so might fail if you use it in a script. See my answer for an alternate approach that tries to circumvent that.

Comment: Yes, the status is 1, and that means failure. 0 status is for success. I'm not inspecting it visually, CircleCI correctly emits red status when I'm doing that.

Comment: @denis.peplin in this case, the status would be `1` no matter whether the compilation succeeded or not because inexisting tag is already considered as a failure. That said, the above simply does not check anything.

Comment: I've just checked that it in two cases: a regular app and an umbrella app. It emits `1` when it's a regular app and `0` when it's an umbrella.

Comment: Interesting. I would consider this being a bug worth reporting.

Comment: Maybe it is, reported if you feel like it. There is a workaround for the problem: I can create one empty test that is always green and mark it with the tag. This way, my answer is still a working solution. But I will use your anyway because it works faster.